# Отдельный сервер изображений

Tags: веб-программирование, изображения

Я хочу использовать в своём проекте возможность лёгкой смены хранилища изображений. То есть пока они у меня на основном сервере в отдельной папке, но позже, я, возможно, захочу вынести их на отдельный поддомен. Кроме того, будет и вообще переезд (смена адреса). То есть нельзя в шаблонах прописывать жёстко полный путь вместе с адресом сервера.
Я правильно понимаю, что лучшее решение - иметь везде в системе переменную, полученную из конфигурации, содержащую нужный адрес, и в шаблонах прописывать все пути с ней?

Comment: Правильно понимаете. В Django, например, есть переменные `STATIC_URL` и `MEDIA_URL`, которые задаются в конфигурационном файле, а потом используются в шаблонах

Answer (score 1):

Вариант — раздавать картинки с поддомена, но уж структуру папок в нем не трогать.

Сегодня `pics.supersite.tld` указывает туда же, где и сам сайт, завтра купите Amazon S3, и там повторите структуру папок с картинками 1:1, и перекинете поддомен `pics` сделав его CNAME'ом `kartinki-1.supersite.tld.amazonaws.com`; послезавтра купите выделенный серв., поставите на него `nginx` и перекинете домен на него.

Никакого шаманства с переменными, шаблонами, динамикой. Только DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос у вас получился риторический. Это ведь очевидно, что если "контейнер" с изображениями будет жить своей жизнью, кочуя по просторам инета, то разумно изменить путь к нему в одном конфигурационном файле, который будет подключен на всех страницах и выдавать переменную или константу с данной информацией на всех страницах проекта.

Comment: Ну, не то, чтобы прям кочует всё время, но поменяется. А менять везде ссылки нереал. Я, собсно, этот способ и описал, но хотел удостовериться в верности.  
Одно но: бывает, пути написаны в JS-скриптах (для подгрузки картинок через JS), как в этом случае? Что-то типа:
    
     <div style='display:none' id='img' data-url='<?=IMG?>'></div>

, где IMG - константа из конфигурации? А JS возьмёт значение отсюда. То есть, как в классической передаче значений из PHP в JS.

Comment: Загружайте конфиг файл для Js скриптов, генерируемый php-скриптом

    /*JSConf.php*/
    var SITE_URL = <?=$conf["STATIC_URL"]?>;


В HTML:

    <script src="JSConf.php"></script>

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай, зачем лишний запрос делать? Лучше в прямо в шаблоне в head все необходимые переменные прописать.

    <script>
    var STATIC_URL = '<?= $conf["STATIC_URL"] ?>';
    </script>

Comment: Да, лучше так.

Comment: А как же можно поступить с CSS?